# JS Compiler into Solidity

Tags: evm, bytecode

Is there a transpiler that takes JS and spits out Solidity? If yes where, if not why not? I was thinking of creating a library that does this to help write smart contracts in JS if it doesn't already exist as I need it for something.

Alternatively is there a compiler that can render JS into EVM byte code - same motivation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think currently there is a transpiler that takes JS and spits out Solidity because how would the transpiler account for fundamental differences between JS and the account model in Solidity in grammars such as modifiers, receive / fallback functions, built-in properties such as block.* and tx.*, inter-contract calls, event definitions and emit() function calls, and assembly statement in Solidity. Similar reasoning for a compiler that can render JS into EVM byte code (compiled from its high-level counterpart Solidity).